# MySQL + time duration based on status

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset like below

```
----------------------------------------------------
| NodeID            | Status  | Time               |
----------------------------------------------------
|  101              | Up      |2016-04-27 10:00:35 |
----------------------------------------------------
|  101              | Down    |2016-04-27 10:43:12 |
----------------------------------------------------
|  101              | Up      |2016-04-27 11:05:48 |
----------------------------------------------------
|  156              | Up      |2016-04-27 08:17:10 |
----------------------------------------------------
|  156              | Up      |2016-04-27 08:56:30 |
----------------------------------------------------
|  156              | Down    |2016-04-27 09:06:12 |
----------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to get the availability ( time % when each application was Up). 
The table cannot have a auto increment field as the records will be deleted on a continuous basis using scheduled jobs.

I tried using row number and self join to get time difference with next record for each rows as :

```
SELECT A.NodeId, A.Status, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,A.time,B.time) AS timedifference 
FROM (

SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,nodeId, status, time FROM sw_node_status,
(SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t) as A 

INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,nodeId, status, time FROM sw_node_status,
(SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
) as B ON B.row_number = (A.row_number + 1 )
ORDER BY A.NodeId ASC
```

But takes a long time to run and gives me back only one record.
The expected output would be as :

---

```
| NodeID            | Status  | Time               | Duration (mins
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  101              | Up      |2016-04-27 10:00:35 | 43 
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  101              | Down    |2016-04-27 10:43:12 | 23
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  101              | Up      |2016-04-27 11:05:48 | 0
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  156              | Up      |2016-04-27 08:17:10 | 39
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  156              | Up      |2016-04-27 08:56:30 | 10
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  156              | Down    |2016-04-27 09:06:12 | 0
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What would be expected output in the given example?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @prev_time:=time,
       nodeId, status, time,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,A.time,@prev_time) AS timedifference 
FROM sw_node_status, (SELECT @prev_time:=some_initial_time) as init
```